# Copy all the files which begin with the same name to a different directory in python

Tags: python, directory, copy

My directory looks like below with few files.

Directory
--111_file.txt
--222_file.txt
--111_file2.txt
--222_sample.txt

I want to copy all the files that starts with 111 to a separate directory and 222 to a different directory. I am confused with how to traverse the directory and find files which start with the same name.

Comment: Its not always 111 or 222, it can have any number of different file path. It has to traverse entire directory and copy files that start with same name to one folder.Also i will not know the name of the file, i just know that it starts with number.

Answer (score 0):

The following bash script copies all the files with pattern matching:

```
cp 111* dir1;
cp 222* dir2;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement that in a program using Python, you can use the [shutil](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html) module, e.g:

```py
# importing shutil module  
import shutil  
  
# Source path  
source = '/Users/path/to/source'
  
# Destination path  
destination = '/Users/path/to/destination'
  
# Move the content of source to destination  
dest = shutil.move(source, destination)
```

To search for files with a condition in directory and subdirectories recursively, you can use `glob` coupling to `re`:

```py
import os
import re
from glob import glob

# Source path 
source = '/Users/path/to/source'

files = glob(source + '/**', recursive=True) # '/**' and recurvise=True allow to search in subdirectories
files_to_move = [f for f in files if re.match('^\d', os.path.split(f)[1])] # '^\d' searchs for every files which start with a digit
```

Comment: Please check the comment

Answer (score 0):

Hey in python you can use `shutil` lib.

For example:

```py
import shutil
import os

prefix_1 = '111'
prefix_2 = '222'

curr_working_dir = os.getcwd()

target1 = 'traget_path_1'
target2 = 'target_path_2'

files = os.listdir() #Path which includes you source files

for file in files:
   if prefix_1 in file:
       shutil.copyfile(curr_working_dir+'/'+file,target_1)
   elif prefix_2 in file:
       shutil.copyfile(curr_working_dir+'/'+file,target_2)
   else:
      pass
```

Best regards

Comment: Please check the comment.